# Finding combinations of a HashSet of Strings

Tags: java, dictionary, set, combinations

I have a `HashMap<String, HashSet>`. The `String` stores the name of the person, and the `HashSet` stores the list of people that are friends with the person.

```
KEY<STRING>   VALUE<HASHSET>
Dave          Steve
Steve         Dave
Bob           Dalton
Dalton        Bob, Sue
Anne          Sue
Sue           Dalton, Anne
```

In the above data, Dave is friends with Steve (line 1 and 2). From line 4, Dalton is friends with Bob and Sue. However, Bob and Sue are not necessarily friends. The program needs to input Bob and Sue as friends. In other words, Bob should be added to Sue's friend list and Sue should be added to Bob's friends list. However, Dalton's friends list may have an infinite amount of people. I am also not allowed to store the friend list data into an `Array` or an `ArrayList`.

One solution I was considering (but haven't tried) was to edit my `read(String name1, String name2)` method. **(Note: In my runner class, whenever this method is called, it is called as `read(name1, name2)` and `read(name2, name1)`)** In short, this method reads in two friendships and adds in the friendship into the map. In the `else` block (if `name1` is already a `key` in the `HashMap`), I was thinking to add in code to take the existing friendlist (which will only have one value) of `name1` and call `read` again.

Here's the `read` method, if you need it

```
private Map<String, Set> friends;

// Adds two friends, name1 and name2, to the HashMap of friendships
public void read(String name1, String name2)
{
    // Temporary HashSet in case a person has more than one friend
    Set<String> strSet = new HashSet<String>();     

    if (!friends.containsKey(name1))
    {
        strSet.add(name2);

        friends.put(name1, strSet);
    }

    else
    {
        strSet.clear();

        // Set strSet to the current friendlist of name1
        strSet = friends.get(name1);            

        strSet.add(name2);

        // Make a new entry in the HashMap with name1 and the updated friend list
        friends.put(name1, strSet);
    }
}
```

Another solution (going off of the title of this thread) is to find all the possible combinations of the friendlist. e.g. if Dalton has Bob, Sue, and Dave in his friend list, I could have a method that finds all possible combinations of two way friendships (remember, order doesn't matter):

```
Bob Sue
Bob Dave
Sue Dave
```

However, I don't know how to code this. Any suggestions?

Comment: So if Dalton was friends with Bob, Sue, and Dave, then you want to make Bob friends with Sue and Dave, Sue friends with Bob and Dave, and Dave friends with Bob and Sue (as well as all three of them being friends with Dalton)?

Comment: @BrianJ Yes, that is correct

Comment: Are you restricted to using HashMap<String, HashSet> exactly to define the relationships?

Comment: @slambeth No, I can use other structures, just not `Arrays`/`ArrayList`s to store data. It also doesn't have to be `<String, HashSet>` either.

Comment: It very much sounds like some sort of graph is needed, and I expect some sort of recursive function for adding friends of friends, but I don't have enough to formulate an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second solution you described is equivalent to a [disjoint-set data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). Your friends end up being in sets, where everyone in each set is friends with everyone else in that set and no one else.

The tricky part of implementing this data structure is merging two sets when you discover that two people in different sets are friends.

This is a naive implementation:

```
public class DisjointFriendSet {
    private final Map<String, Set<String>> personToFriends = new HashMap<>();

    /**
     * Includes the person themselves in their group of friends.
     * 
     * If no friendships have been registered for this person, then returns a set
     * containing just themselves.
     * 
     * @param person
     * @return
     */
    public Set<String> getFriends(String person) {
        if(personToFriends.containsKey(person)) {
            return personToFriends.get(person);
        } else {
            final Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
            result.add(person);
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void addFriendship(String person1, String person2) {
        final Set<String> friends1 = getFriends(person1);
        final Set<String> friends2 = getFriends(person2);

        if(friends1 == friends2) {
            return;
        } else {
            personToFriends.put(person1, friends1);
            friends1.addAll(friends2);
            for(String person: friends2) {
                personToFriends.put(person, friends1);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @return All unique friendship groups
     */
    public Collection<Set<String>> getAllFriendshipGroups() {
        return new HashSet<>(personToFriends.values());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final DisjointFriendSet disjointFriendSet = new DisjointFriendSet();

        disjointFriendSet.addFriendship("Alice","Beowulf");
        disjointFriendSet.addFriendship("Charity","Donald");
        disjointFriendSet.addFriendship("Eduardo","Frank");
        disjointFriendSet.addFriendship("Grendel","Harriet");

        System.out.println("Friendship groups: "+disjointFriendSet.getAllFriendshipGroups());

        System.out.println("Adding friendship between Grendel and Beowulf");
        disjointFriendSet.addFriendship("Grendel","Beowulf");
        System.out.println("Friendship groups: "+disjointFriendSet.getAllFriendshipGroups());
        System.out.println();

        for(String person: new String[]{"Alice","Beowulf","Charity","Donald","Eduardo","Frank","Grendel","Harriet","Zod"}) {
            System.out.println(person+"'s friends: "+disjointFriendSet.getFriends(person));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pseudo code approach (I can look up the Java later)

Assume at each addition that all friends of friends are properly matched.

Take the two new inputs, and create a temporary collection of all of their friends as well as the input values.

For every value in the temporary collection, add every other value as a friend. (A set should only maintain unique values, but you can explicitly check if need be).

This may not be the most efficient solution (at every step, half of the additions would be duplicates), but it should be a starting point.

```
Func (friend1, friend2)
    tempSet = masterSet(friend1).Hashset
    UNION
    masterSet(friend2).Hashset
    UNION
    friend1, friend2

     foreach (friend in tempSet)
         foreach(otherFriend in tempSet - friend)
             friend.AddFriend(otherFriend)
             otherFriend.AddFriend(friend)
```